# Using Dagger 2 to inject values when deserializing with Jackson

Tags: jackson, dagger, dagger-2

When deserializing, Jackson will fetch the values of any properties of an object marked with [`@JacksonInject`](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureValueInjection) from a mapping supplied to the `ObjectMapper` instead of from the JSON.  This mapping is specified by calling  [`ObjectMapper.setInjectableValues()`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#setInjectableValues(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.InjectableValues))  and providing an [`InjectableValues`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/InjectableValues.html) object which can look up the values to be injected on request.

It is fairly easy to create such an object with Guice (as [`jackson-module-guice`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-guice) does).  First, when you create your object mapper, you inject the `Injector` and wrap it in an `InjectableValues` implementation which simply forwards requests to the `Injector` (the class of the thing to be injected and its annotations are available).

To make this work with Dagger 2, we would need to be able to take a `Class` object (and relevant annotations) and inject an instance at runtime.  However, given Dagger 2's code-generation approach, this does not seem to be possible.  Am I missing something?